# Get the uri/path value of an image in the field template in Drupal 7

Tags: image, drupal-7, uri, field

I have created a custom field template for an image - field--field_images.tpl.php with the following code:

```
<?php $url = file_create_url($field_images['uri']);
$url = parse_url($url);
$imglink = $url['path'];
?>
<div id="slideshow">
<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>    
<div data-thumb="<?php print render($imglink); ?>" data-src="<?php print render($imglink); ?>" data-time="1500" data-trasPeriod="4000" data-target="_blank" ></div>           
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

currently $imglink returns the value of the root folder "www". I need it to return the path to the image file associated with the field e.g "http://www.mysite.com/sites/default/files/image.jpg" any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I think I'm almost there. Here is the code in my field-field_images.tpl.php file:
`<?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>

    <div data-thumb="<?php $img_src = $element['#object']->field_images['und'][0]['uri']; $link = image_style_url('thumbnail', $img_src); print ($link);   ?>" data-src="<?php $img_src = $element['#object']->field_images['und'][0]['uri']; $link = file_create_url($img_src); print ($link);   ?>" data-time="1500" data-trasPeriod="4000" data-target="_blank" ><?php render($item); ?></div>

   <?php endforeach; ?>`

and you can see the output here: http://www.kfpa.co.za/dev/?q=node/2

The one problem is that it loops through and creates the correct number of elements for the uploaded images, but when it creates the URLs it's only creating for the item as specified for by 'x' in `<?php $img_src = $element['#object']->field_images['und'][x]['uri'];` i.e if I change 'x' to '2' the third photo displays. How do I change this code so that it finds the correct URL for corresponding image in the loop?

Comment: can you please tell that what you get after echoing `$field_images['uri']`?

Comment: It outputs `http://mydomain.co.za/` where 'mydomain' is the domain name

Comment: I just realised that var $field_images is not defined. I'll take another stab at it and let you know if it works.

Comment: aah, that might be the issue. My answer assumed you wanted to get a "styled" image. so file_create_url "IS" the function that does your work. The whole thing fails cause your $field_images doesn't have the uri in the first place.

Comment: Did you get this working? I would like to know how you used file_create_url($uri) to get your field image src.

Comment: @Chris In the end I used this code (but suspect I could have achieved what I needed with views)  `<?php $n = 0; $k = 0; ?> <a href="<?php $img_src = $element['#object']->field_cover_image['und'][$k++]['uri']; $link = image_style_url('cover_image', $img_src); print ($link); ?>" > <img src="<?php $img_src = $element['#object']->field_cover_image['und'][$n++]['uri']; $link = image_style_url('profile_gallery_hover', $img_src); print ($link); ?>" data-link="?q=node/<?php print $element['#object']->nid; ?>" data-title="<?php print $element['#object']->title; ?>" /> </a>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to tweak flexslider to show an image pager. The code is very similar to yours, but I think in the end I will use field_slideshow module to achieve the image gallery that I want.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a uri you can use [image_style_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_path/7) to create the image path ( style specific if required).

EDIT:
For obtaining original image path use [file_create_url($uri)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7)

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to respond, I did try that however it outputs the path like this `http://mydomain.co.za/?q=sites/media/styles/thumbnail/public&itok=Q4Jh-VWn` whereas I need the path to the original like this `http://mydomain.co.za/?q=sites/media/myimage.jpg` any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i saw you used data-thumb in your code, so assumed you wanted to use a thumbnail size of the image. i have updated the answer with a function that you can use to get the original url from the uri.